The Hydra tool is not checking the entire wordlist
I recently used the Hydra tool and want to share my experience. I created a custom word list and placed the password in the 10th position. When I used the command
hydra -l msfadmin -P list.txt <target_ip> telnet

it worked fine. Then, I shifted the same password from the 10th to the 30th row in the list and used the same command again, but it couldn't find the password. However, when I increased the number of threads with
hydra -t 35 -l msfadmin -P list.txt <target_ip> telnet

it worked.
Now, if I shift the password from the 30th to the 60th row and use the same command
hydra -t 35 -l msfadmin -P list.txt <target_ip> telnet

it doesn't work. It seems that I have to provide a value to -t greater than or equal to the row number where the password is located for it to work. However, the limitation of -t is that it can't be greater than 64.
Can someone explain what might be happening and what the solution could be?

I have no experience with this whatsoever, but maybe the target server recognizes many unsuccessful tries in such short time as an attack. Maybe it temporarily disallows access for the attacker (i.e. for you) even if the right password is used eventually.

@KamilMaciorowski i think the same way, but i mention if i set the threat to same aur higher then the row number (where the password exist). and the target service is from 'vulnerable machine' so there is no rule set to stop checking multiple password
